# Can you change the Authority, ClientId, and DefaultAccessTokenScopes in Msal Authentication after adding it to the service provider

Tags: c#, authentication, azure-active-directory, blazor, azure-ad-msal

I want to be able to call a different app registers from a single web app. I'm not sure how to go about it. At first I thought I might be able to add multiple MsalAuthentications to my service provider than call a specific one. I couldn't get that to work, so now I'm wondering if it is possible to change the options of the MsalAuthentication I add at the begining.

Here is how I am adding MSAL Authentication:

```
builder.Services.AddMsalAuthentication(options =>
{
    var authentication = options.ProviderOptions.Authentication;
    authentication.Authority = FakeADTenant.TenantAddress;
    authentication.ClientId = FakeADTenant.AppId;
    authentication.ValidateAuthority = true;

    options.ProviderOptions.DefaultAccessTokenScopes.Add(FakeADTenant.TokenScope);
});
```

On the other end, when the log in button is clicked, I'm using this page to log in:

```
@page "/authentication/{action}"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication

<RemoteAuthenticatorView Action="@Action" />

@code{
    [Parameter] public string Action { get; set; }
}
```

I'm thinking I could possible change the options in the code before RemoteAuthenticatorView gets called. I only want to change the authentication.Authority, authentication.ClientId, and options.ProviderOptions.DefaultAccessTokenScopes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, as any OAuth provider, you cannot change the clientId, The Authority is the OAuth provider url. Redirect URIs must match URis register for the client. And you can send any of client allowed scopes in the authorize request.

Comment: Interesting, so is there any way to have multiple client Id's to choose from when making the authorize request? Could I add multiple OAuth provider's with different client id's and then specify the provider during the authorize request?

Comment: Use IdentityServer4 to do that

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot!